# I need to print my output in the form c0 + c1 x + c2 x^2 and goes on. is there a way to it?

Tags: python

I need to print my output in the form c0 + c1 x + c2 x^2 and goes on. is there a way to it ?

```
for i in range(len(finalresult)):
    c_i = round(finalresult[i][len(finalresult)], 6)

print("%s + %s*x^1+%s*x^2" %(c_1,c_2,c_3))
```

Comment: Just for the purposes of [a good question](/help/how-to-ask): please add the missing code that declares (a representative) `finalresult`.

Answer (score 1):

Sure - use string formatting.

Some contreived example with random coefficients, using enumerate to get the cardinality of the `x` and some str.join to glue it together:

```
from random import choices, randint

k = {0:"", 1:"*x"}
for _ in range(10):
    coeff = choices(range(-200,210), k=randint(3,9))
    print(''.join(f'{"+" if i > 0 <= v else ""}{v}{f"""{(k.get(i,"*x^"+str(i)))}""" if i > 1 else "*x" if i == 1 else ""}' 
                  for i,v in enumerate(coeff)))
```

Output:

```
122+10*x+3*x^2-122*x^3+105*x^4-63*x^5+137*x^6+199*x^7
-47-108*x-197*x^2-80*x^3+192*x^4+31*x^5-22*x^6-73*x^7
-25+190*x-74*x^2+162*x^3+23*x^4+183*x^5
-189-85*x-150*x^2
96-88*x+104*x^2+109*x^3+157*x^4-97*x^5-65*x^6-189*x^7+136*x^8
145+14*x+131*x^2-14*x^3-156*x^4
102+131*x-93*x^2-65*x^3+60*x^4
-142+85*x+29*x^2+12*x^3
-24-151*x-179*x^2+176*x^3
98-40*x+100*x^2-156*x^3-99*x^4-50*x^5-83*x^6+40*x^7
```

Comment: by the way, `i > 0 and v >= 0` is the same as `i > 0 <= v`

Comment: `f"*x^{i}"*(i > 0)` also works for removing the 0th degree term :)

Comment: Note: op didn't want `^1` shown

Comment: Ah, it's in their code but not their title or post... wonder what they actually want...

Comment: @OneCricketeer  - fixed, thx.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't have negative exponents, you can use an iterator over just a list of the coefficients

```
finalresult = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
it = iter(finalresult)

output = [next(it), "{}x".format(next(it))]
for exp, val in enumerate(it, start=2):
  output.append("{}x^{}".format(val, exp))

print(' + '.join(map(str, output)))
```

Output - `1 + 2x + 3x^2 + 4x^3 + 5x^4 + 6x^5`

If you want to handle special cases like ignoring zeros, or negative numbers by changing `+` to `-`, then you'll want a regular loop rather than using `join`